# Book from 1960, a girl keeps blacking out and going back in time to the time of the druids

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, time

I read this in grade school so think the book was probably from the 1960s or 1970s.

The (female) protagonist would black out and go back in time. I remember druids and Stonehenge and also there was a deaf/mute girl.

Answer (score 3):

any chance that it was "[A Swiftly Tilting Planet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Swiftly_Tilting_Planet)" by Madeline L'Engle.

It looks like you can purchase it for slightly more than shipping on Amazon. ([link](http://amzn.com/0312368607))

Comment: Why do you feel that book matches? Incidentally, *An Acceptable Time* might be a slightly closer match.

Comment: I have read the Swiftly Tilting Planet though it has been a while.  It has a girl (Meg) and traversing in time including to era of Druids.  Madeline also favors use of standing stones (aka star-watching rock) as icons.  The book came out in the later 70's so it is in the era.  It won a national book award so it would have had some popularity.

Comment: Swiftly Tilting Planet has Meg's brother, Charles Wallace traveling, and her following with him in a psychic manner.  (Kything, per the story.) I don't recall Stonehenge, no a deaf/mute girl, nor does Meg blackout to travel -- she actually has to concentrate to kythe.  It's a good story, tho :)